# Notepad++ Adding return or newline after ip address

Tags: notepad++

I have document that has over 10,000 lines of code that I need to script and need to add a new line after it finds the ip address in document.

there is code that varies and differs on line before and after the ip address which is also different and ranges all over.

I was able to figure out how to find the ip address but cant figure out how to instead of replacing it just adding a new line after it.

\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}

Answer (score 2):

In the Notepad++ Replace dialog, check the `Regular expression` option in the Search Mode section. Use `(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})` for the "Find what" field. That's the regular expression you already have, wrapped in parentheses so you can refer to it again in the "Replace with" field.

In the "Replace with" field, enter `\1\n`. The `\1` part refers to whatever was found by the expression in parentheses in the "Find what" field, and the `\n` adds a newline character.